# How to change the head of a model to accept vary size input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have a language model:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
from transformers import RobertaModel
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

checkpoint = 'roberta-base'

test_question = ['this is a string', 'this is another string but longer']

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
```

I'm trying to change the head of the model to have 4 linear layers with 512 neurons each:

```
class QModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.base_model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(12288, 512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        input_ids, attn_mask = torch.tensor(x['input_ids']), torch.tensor(x['attention_mask'])
        outputs = self.base_model(input_ids, attention_mask=attn_mask)
        # new head
        outputs = self.dropout(outputs[0])
        outputs = outputs.view(-1, 12288)
        outputs = self.linear1(outputs)
        outputs = self.dropout(outputs)
        outputs = self.linear2(outputs)
        outputs = self.dropout(outputs)
        outputs = self.linear3(outputs)
        outputs = self.dropout(outputs)
        outputs = self.linear4(outputs)                            
        return outputs

model = QModel()

model(tokenizer(test_question, padding=True))
```

But if I change the input size:

```
test_question = ['this is a string', 'this is another string but longer', 'another input']
```

I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 12288]' is invalid for input of size 18432
```

I understand that it arises from the `12288` value in `linear1`, but I'm not sure how to flatten it in the appropriate way to accept multiple inputs

Comment: What is the output shape of base_model? When it varies, you need to pad it.

Comment: @cronoik Isn't the output shape of the last hidden layers for a model is fixed? I believe Roberta is 768

Comment: The hidden_size for `roberta-base` is 768 but the seqlen can differ. So the output will be [bsz, seqlen, 768].